# Directly modifying array elements in foreach causes value to overwrite the next element

Tags: php, foreach, reference, text-parsing

My simple loop takes a list of coordinates and placenames, such as this:

```
(59.436961) (24.753575) (Revel, Estonia) (Born)
(-34.847745) (138.507362) (Port Adelaide) (Disembarked)
(-33.177085) (138.010057) (Port Pirie) (Residence before enlistment)
```

It `preg_split`s them into the array $coords, which works great. I then iterate through them in a foreach loop. My question is why does this:

```
foreach ($coords as &$marker){
    $marker = preg_split('/\\) \\(|\\(|\\)/', $marker, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
print_r($coords);
```

Result in this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 59.436961
            [1] => 24.753575
            [2] => Revel, Estonia
            [3] => Born
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -34.847745
            [1] => 138.507362
            [2] => Port Adelaide
            [3] => Disembarked
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => -34.847745
            [1] => 138.507362
            [2] => Port Adelaide
            [3] => Disembarked
        )

)
```

(Note that elements [1] and [2] are identical) - but this:

```
foreach ($coords as $marker){
    $marker_array[] = preg_split('/\\) \\(|\\(|\\)/', $marker, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
print_r($marker_array);
```

Result in this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 59.436961
            [1] => 24.753575
            [2] => Revel, Estonia
            [3] => Born
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -34.847745
            [1] => 138.507362
            [2] => Port Adelaide
            [3] => Disembarked
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => -33.177085
            [1] => 138.010057
            [2] => Port Pirie
            [3] => Residence before enlistment
        )

)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or don't know about, when I attempt to modify elements directly in the loop?

Comment: Use a `for`, not a `foreach`. Or better use `array_walk`.

Comment: Both has identical output, see https://eval.in/403729 and https://eval.in/403728, I don't see any problem

Comment: Then something must be happening when I echo the arrays into Javascript - could it be significant that this loop occurs within a while loop, but the echoing occurs outside it?

Comment: Show more code around this if you want help with that.

Comment: Do an `unset($marker);` directly after your `foreach` loop; otherwise you run a high risk of messing up your data if you use the variable name `$marker` again later on in your script.

Comment: It seems that no one can Reproduce this error, so it should be closed as Off-topic.  As an aside, because you are parsing text which contains float data, I recommend making iterated calls of `sscanf()` so that you can explicitly type cast those numeric substring.  https://3v4l.org/ekXVb This is a feature that `preg_` functions do not afford.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.6 I do not see the described behaviour. How do you parse the raw list?

When I run:

```
<?php

$coords = array('(59.436961) (24.753575) (Revel, Estonia) (Born)',
    '(-34.847745) (138.507362) (Port Adelaide) (Disembarked)',
    '(-33.177085) (138.010057) (Port Pirie) (Residence before enlistment)');

foreach ($coords as &$marker){
    $marker = preg_split('/\\) \\(|\\(|\\)/', $marker, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
print_r($d);
```

it gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 59.436961
            [1] => 24.753575
            [2] => Revel, Estonia
            [3] => Born
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -34.847745
            [1] => 138.507362
            [2] => Port Adelaide
            [3] => Disembarked
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => -33.177085
            [1] => 138.010057
            [2] => Port Pirie
            [3] => Residence before enlistment
        )

)
```

But I wouldn't recoomend using this crazy construction!

If you parse it from text, then simply use `preg_match_all` with pattern something like this:

```
'~\(()\)\s*\(()\)\s*\(()\)\s*\(()\)~mu'
```

**Even if you have data in array, I highly recommned that you use `preg_match` for predictable data matching indstead of `preg_split` for this purpose. But noone becamed master at day one...**